# Multiple PyTorch networks running in parallel on different CPUs

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pytorch

I’m trying to have different PyTorch neural networks run in parallel on different CPUs but am finding that it isn’t leading to any sort of speed up compared to running them sequentially.

Below is my code that replicates the issue exactly. If you run this code it shows that with 2 processes it takes roughly twice as long as running it with 1 process but really it should take the same amount of time.

```
import time
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
import gym
import numpy as np
import copy
import torch.nn as nn
import torch

class NN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, output_dim):
        nn.Module.__init__(self)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(4, 50)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(50, 500)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(500, 5000)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(5000, output_dim)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.relu(self.fc3(x))
        x = self.fc4(x)
        return x

def Worker(ix):
  print("Starting training for worker ", ix)
  env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
  model = NN(2)
  for _ in range(2000):
    model(torch.Tensor(env.reset()))
  print("Finishing training for worker ", ix)

def overall_process(num_workers):
  workers = []
  for ix in range(num_workers):
    worker = mp.Process(target=Worker, args=(ix, ))
    workers.append(worker)
  [w.start() for w in workers]  
  for worker in workers:
    worker.join()

  print("Finished Training")  
  print(" ")

start = time.time()
overall_process(1)
print("Time taken: ", time.time() - start)
print(" ")

start = time.time()
overall_process(2)
print("Time taken: ", time.time() - start)
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening and how to fix it?

I thought that it is maybe because PyTorch networks automatically implement CPU parallelism in the background and so I tried adding the below 2 lines but it doesn’t always resolve the issue:

```
torch.set_num_threads(1)
torch.set_num_interop_threads(1)
```

Comment: How many cores? AFAIK PyTorch uses all available cores via MKL hence one network might be trained approximately twice as fast using all cores and that would explain your results. Try to use `torch.set_num_threads(cores // 2)` without `torch.multiprocessing` and see if this changes anything.

Comment: doing torch.set_num_threads(1) doesn't seem to solve the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to set torch.set_num_threads(1) at the beginning of each worker process (rather than in the main process) as explained here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/multiple-networks-running-in-parallel-on-different-cpus/70482